# Anidar pdf Genexus 16

Tags: genexus

estoy trabajando con una aplicación en GX16 U11 con java 1.8, lo que necesito es Anidar varios archivos PDf y poder de todos esos hacer uno.

Les agradezco alguno ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías hacer con el UC [**PDFTools**](https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?pdftools,en), puedes ver varios ejemplos de lo que se puede lograr con el mismo en [**este link**](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?11611,PDF%20Tools%20Project,).

Este sería un ejemplo para concatenar N archivos PDFs:

```
// Concat Files EXAMPLE
 &files.Add("…DocIn01.pdf") // &files is a character Collection variable
 &files.Add("…DocIn02.pdf")
 &files.Add("…DocIn03.pdf")
 &res = &PDFTools.ConcatFiles(&files,"…DocOut.pdf") // &PDFTools is PDFTools type (External Object)
 msg(&res)
```

Comment: Agradezco el comentario, estuve buscando y me descargue unos xpz con ejemplos. pero los mismos me están dando un error.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?